# C# - Iterate over all possible pairwise combinations of array contents

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

If I have a C# array of objects and want to iterate over all pairwise combinations, how is this best accomplished? For:

```
int[] list = new int[3] {100, 200, 300};
```

This would look like:

```
100, 200
100, 300
200, 300
```

Obviously, I want a function that can take an array of any size, and preferably is generic so that any object type could work.

Comment: Why not just use a nested loop?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
public static IList<Tuple<T,T>> GetPairs<T>(IList<T> list)    
{
    IList<Tuple<T,T>> res = new List<Tuple<T,T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Count(); j++)
        {
            res.Add(new Tuple<T, T>(list[i], list[j]));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] input = new int[] {100, 200, 300};

List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>();

for(int i=0; i<input.Length-1; i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<input.Length; j++)
    {
        result.Add(new int[]{input[i], input[j]});
    }
}
```

Comment: the first loop should have `loop condition` as `i<input.Length-1`

Comment: I don't see why? I just ran it and have the exact results he wishes.

Comment: Yes, but the last loop `i=input.Length-1` is redundant, at that loop `j=input.Length` and nothing is executed more, I don't mean you code doesn't work, just redundant a little.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] arr = { 800, 11, 50, 771, 649, 770, 240, 9 };      

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j= i; j< arr.Length; j++)
            {
    if(i!=j)


                    //Console.Write(arr[i] + " " + arr[j]);
Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " " + arr[j]);

            }
        }
```

Instead of 'int' you can take Object type. Then you need to maintain further checking.

Comment: this may output `800 11` and `11 800`, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: This provides all permutations, not all combinations.

Comment: @Doug My code provides exact solution as Your sample question data is.

Comment: (You'll want to use WriteLine instead of Write.)

Comment: The down vote should be there, as you use 'if (i != j)' instead of just initializing j to i + 1. This is a check that is totally unnecessary.